# Odoo: How to hide create or edit button based in some condition using python?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want that when the status of a product is canceled the edit and cancel button doesn't appear.

I can't use:

```xml
<form string="form_view_string" edit="false" create="false" >
```

How is it only when there is the condition I want to use python. I tried it this way and hide the buttons on all forms of this model:

```py
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(Entity, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
                                              context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    if view_type == 'form':
       for node_form in doc.xpath("//form"):
          node_form.set("create", 'false')

    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

and when I add a conditional it shows edit and create buttons:

```py
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(Entity, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
                                              context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    if view_type == 'form' and [some_condition]:
       for node_form in doc.xpath("//form"):
          node_form.set("create", 'false')

    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

Comment: the solution is in JavaScript, fields_view_get is called only one time to load the définition of the view, I hope one day they implement some mechanism to handle this in XML like we di in attrs, but you can achieve this by javascript but it's not easy

Comment: It will be done by creating security group for that button based on giving access.